# Loop through multiple lists where list names have the same prefix

Tags: python, list

I have few lists like this: (Please note in reality the number of lists could be much much more than here. But all list names will have the same prefix, in this case all list names start with LIST).

```
LISTA = ['E', 'H']
LISTB = ['G','C']
LISTC = ['B','G','D']
LISTD = ['C']
LISTE = ['A']
LISTF = ['G']
LISTG = ['B','C','F']
LISTH = ['A']
```

I want to get the output like this. the format of output is not important here. only contents are important.

```
LISTA: ['E','H']
LISTB: ['G','C','F','D']
LISTC: ['B','G','F','D']
LISTD: ['B','C','G','F']
LISTE: ['A','H']
LISTF: ['B','C','D','G']
LISTG: ['B','C','D','F']
LISTH: ['A','E']
```

Let me explain:
LISTB has G and C. So go to LISTG and LISTC and look at their contents and append it to LISTB. Now again within contents of LISTG and LISTC, go to other LISTs like this and gather all the letters, remove duplicates and place in LISTB.

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, so what's your question exactly? Check out [ask]. Note that questions should be about a specific problem, but there's a lot going on here, so asking about the whole task would be too much. You can [edit] if needed.

Comment: Where do you have these lists? Are they in a text file? Side question: Why do you have soo many of them? Also, is the output supposed to be written to a file, or stored in a dict?

Comment: FWIW, you might want to read [How do I create variable variables?](/q/1373164/4518341). It'd be a lot easier to manage these lists if they were in a dict, like `lists = {'A': ['E','H'], ...}`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Good job providing a minimal reproducible example! What you could do better in the future is to show **what you've tried**. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if the question was not clear enough or if this question was not at par with this site. Not sure if there is a way to delete this question too.

My main dilemma was how to loop through the LISTs in one go when they have the same prefix. Anyways, through @smac89, I got the idea of converting the input to a dict. The input is coming from a different API and we can control the input format. here I am posting the answer in case anybody might want to know.

```
LIST = {'A': ['E', 'H'], 
        'B': ['G','C'], 
        'C': ['B','G','D'],
        'D': ['C'],
        'E': ['A'],
        'F': ['G'],
        'G': ['B','C','F'],
        'H': ['A']
       }

for _ in range(3):
  for k,v in LIST.items():
    temp = []
    for i in v:
      for j in LIST[i]:
        if j != k and \
          j not in LIST[k] and \
          j not in temp:
          temp.append(j)
    for x in temp:
      LIST[k].append(x)

print(LIST)

{'A': ['E', 'H'],
 'B': ['G', 'C', 'F', 'D'],
 'C': ['B', 'G', 'D', 'F'],
 'D': ['C', 'B', 'G', 'F'],
 'E': ['A', 'H'],
 'F': ['G', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 'G': ['B', 'C', 'F', 'D'],
 'H': ['A', 'E']}
```

Comment: Here is the [PEP8 standard](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#should-a-line-break-before-or-after-a-binary-operator), which contains how to break up your long condition, and other useful conventions people follow in Python! Also, as a rule of thumb you should generally avoid using `\\` - you can often replace it with something more readable.